# Pattern index not getting used in my postgres query

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

My query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM all_persons
WHERE ((("email") ilike ('abc.com%')))
ORDER BY "lastOrderAt" DESC
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 20
```

I have already added indexes on table on column `emailvarchar_pattern_ops`.

Using explain I found that index is not used. Can someone guide that is the index wrongly created or how can I speed up the query?

Comment: Could you please share the complete DDL for the index, and the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for this statement? (all in plain text)

Comment: ```
{ 'QUERY PLAN': 'Limit  (cost=1000.48..62461.59 rows=20 width=831)' },
  { 'QUERY PLAN':
     '  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.48..136214.92 rows=44 width=831)' },
  { 'QUERY PLAN': '        Workers Planned: 4' },
  { 'QUERY PLAN':
     '        ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using all_persons_lastorderat_index on all_persons_persons_aggregate  (cost=0.42..135209.62 rows=11 width=831)' },
  { 'QUERY PLAN':
     '              Filter: ((email)::text ~~* \'abc.com%\'::text)' }
```

Comment: This is hard to read, please update the original question, but it's also not the result from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers).

Comment: There is an update to the question. The index is working when i use "like" but it does not work when i use "ilike" . Can you tell why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

varchar_pattern_ops is case sensitive. So it doesn't support ILIKE.

You can make sure the column is stored in all lower case, make sure the pattern is also all lower case, and then just use LIKE rather than ILIKE.  Or you can convert them to lower case on fly, and have it use an index which is a functional index.

Or you can use a trigram index (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html), which does support ILIKE, but will be less efficient than a btree if the wildcard is always at the end of the pattern.